# Missing man pages in Cygwin for system calls

Tags: cygwin, manpage

I installed the cygwin-doc package when installing cygwin, apart from C/C++ development packages. When I run 'man memset', I get the man page as expected, but running man for system calls like lstat and pipe returns with the complaint 'No manual entry'. Are these man pages available in a separate package that I need to install ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe you could accept the only, and correct, answer?

Answer (score 27):

You need to install the package man-pages-posix.

Comment: I had a similar problem. 'man printf' worked but 'man memset' didn't work. After installing this man-pages-posix, it works. Thanks !